# Orbit Controls doesn't work with no error

Tags: three.js

I would like to implement Orbit Control in my program but when I followed exactly each step of some tutorial, nothing happen.
This is my code :

```
    import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.1/build/three.module.js';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.127.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    camera.position.set( 2, 3, 2 );
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);

    var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

and this is what it's looks like :
[Code Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE8oT.png)
but nothing happen. It doesn't rotate or zoom.
Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I used this import :

```
import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

And the main difference is than I added :

```
controls.addEventListener('change',render);

function render(){
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```